# Athena CTAS saves json as string with special char escaped

Tags: json, amazon-athena

I'm creating a new table using CTAS in athena, everything works fine except json string in the raw table (not defined as a `struct`).

It was

```
"screen_orientation":"{"angle":"0"}",
```

Now becomes:

```
"screen_orientation":"{\"angle\":\"0\"}",
```

CTAS statement is straight forward:

```
CREATE TABLE destination_table
WITH (
    format='JSON',
    partitioned_by=ARRAY['partition_date'],
    write_compression='GZIP'
)
AS
SELECT * FROM src_table
```

Source column is of type `string`.

Is there anyway I could prevent this from happening? I can't redefine the source table's column definition due to permission issue.

Comment: can you please share the CTAS? What is the original type for this column in the source table (you can use `select typeof(colum_name) from table` for this)?

Comment: CTAS is as simple as create as select * from src_table. Original column is string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior is expected in Athena. For example if I run below query where I am casting a string to JSON then the double quotes are escaped by backslash(\).

SQL:

```
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT
    CAST('{"test": "value"}' AS JSON) AS hello_msg
)
SELECT * FROM dataset
```

Output:

[image]

But you can always work around this by using `json_format` function as shown below :

SQL:

```
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT
  json_format(JSON '{"test": "value"}' ) as hello_msg
)
SELECT * FROM dataset
```

Output:

[image]

So you can add `json_format` to your select query in CTAS statement which will not embed these backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

If your json comes as a string you can also use `json_parse`:

```
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT
  json_parse('{"test": "value"}') as hello_msg
)
SELECT * FROM dataset
```