# How do I Unnest varchar to json in Athena

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery, presto, amazon-athena

I am crawling data from Google Big Query and staging them into Athena.
One of the columns crawled as string, contains json :

```
{
   "key": "Category",
   "value": {
        "string_value": "something"
}
```

I need to unnest these and flatten them to be able to use them in a query. I require key and string value (so in my query it will be where Category = something

I have tried the following :

```
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT cast(json_column as json) as json_column
  from "thedatabase"
  LIMIT 10
)
SELECT
    json_extract_scalar(json_column, '$.value.string_value') AS string_value
FROM dataset
```

which is returning null.
Casting the json_column as json adds \ into them :

```
"[{\"key\":\"something\",\"value\":{\"string_value\":\"app\"}}
```

If I use replace on the json, it doesn't allow me as it's not a varchar object.

So how do I extract the values from the some_column field?

Comment: try json_format with JSON instead of casting. check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73642778/4326922

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy I would argue OP is looking for `json_parse` in this case.

Comment: @GuruStron This is still doable by just passing JSON "JSON string" to json_parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Presto's `json_extract_scalar` actually supports extracting just from the varchar (string) value :

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(json_column) AS (
 values ('{
   "key": "Category",
   "value": {
        "string_value": "something"
}}')
)

--query
SELECT
    json_extract_scalar(json_column, '$.value.string_value') AS string_value
FROM dataset;
```

Output:

| string_value |
| --- |
| something |

2. Casting to json will encode data as json (in case of string you will get a double encoded one), not parse it, use `json_parse` (in this particular case it is not needed, but there are cases when you will want to use it):

```sql
-- query
SELECT
    json_extract_scalar(json_parse(json_column), '$.value.string_value') AS string_value
FROM dataset;
```

Comment: I'll give it a whirl and let you go

Comment: okay so there were [ ] in the column, so had to use REPLACE(REPLACE(json_column,'[',''),']','')